# What drinks can be paired to a particular legend or myth?

Tags: history, pairing, drinking

What drinks can be paired to a particular [legend](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legend) or [myth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Myth)?

We all know that that many people drink to the legendary person of [St Patrick](http://www.wrdw.com/content/news/Saint-Patricks-Day-The-History-Myths-and-Traditions-Explained-416411623.html). But what I am interested in is in knowing if there are any drinks associated (paired) with a particular legend or myth (Christian or otherwise) and not simply to an historic or legendary person in some general sense. In other words, the pairing must associated to a particular event within a legend or myth.

I am not willing to include [folklore](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Folklore) at the moment!

Comment: Are we talking specific drinks? Or more like legends associated with drinking? The 8 druken gods of chinese druken boxing (rice wine)... or even lengendary drinks? Nectar was the drink of the greek gods...

Comment: @ModernApostles I am talking specific drinks.

Answer (score 2):

Judaeo-Christian, Greek and Roman mythologies have links to wine.
Pastafarians have a goat that gives beer from it's udder.
Norsk myhtology references mead.

And then you can always read articles from the [Lords of the Drinks](https://lordsofthedrinks.com/category/folklore-and-mythology/).